# Saving output of Warp Command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using the command WARP in image processing in MATLAB.

```
[x,y,z] = cylinder;
I = imread('testpat1.png');
warp(x,y,z,I);
```

Above is the example code for using WARP given in MATLAB. But I am not able to save the output of this command. If I do imwrite, just 1 X 1 matrix is saved.

Can anyone help me this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the following line of code to get the handle to the resulting surface object:

```
h = warp(x, y, z, I);
```

You can then access properties of that surface using `get(h, 'property')`

A list of the available properties is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surface_props.html)

For example if you want to get the X coordinates you would do: `Xcoords = get(h, 'XData');`

hope that helps!

---

This is based on the comments below.

```
fig = figure, warp(x, y, z, I);
print(fig, '-r80','-dtiff','image2.tif')
```

Comment: I want to save the image displayed by the warp command. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Ok, well that's fairly easy then.  If you just want to save the figure window use the following command: `print(h, '-r80', '-dtiff', 'image2.tif'); `  The `-r80` specifies 80 dpi for saving and `-dtiff` specifies the .tif formatting.  You can refence the `print` command for more details.

Comment: And FWIW you could pull the X Y Z data and the CData (for coloring) and generate a 3D matrix that you could then save using the imwrite command.

Comment: When I do h = warp, h gets a float value, not an image matrix

Comment: Ok, that's because of a small oversight on my part.  I'd imagine the error you got probably said something about figure handles and what not.  All you need to do is what I've put in my editted post.

Comment: No porblem at all.  If you're feeling super daring you can try the other method when you have some time =P